# ASP.NET Identity2 Company-Staff-Roles relationships handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with Identity 2 to create a relationship of Company, User and Roles.

Here is the model for Company and UserProfile(extends from IdentityUser):

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Staff { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

As its a One to Many relationship, I am getting the all list of company with the below code in my repository clas:

```
public override IQueryable<Company> All()
{
    return this.Context.Set<Company>().Include(s => s.Staff.Select(r => r.Roles));
}
```

And when I return this data in JSON format to the client, I need to model it using the following ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }
    public int StaffCount { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I map the value from repository to the View Model:

```
var all = UOW.CompanyRepository.All()
if (all != null)
{
    return Ok(all.Select(d => new CustomerViewModel { Id = d.CompanyId.ToString(), CompanyName = d.Name, OwnerEmail = "owner@mycompany.com", StaffCount = d.Staff.Count() }).ToList());
}
```

"Owner" is a role assinged to only one user/staff in each Company. 
My problem is now, how do I get the "Owner" emails?

Comment: `s.Staff.Select(r => r.Roles)` what does this projection achieve when calling `All()`?

Comment: @CallumLinington, that was to make sure all staff's and each staff roles are returned. FYI, I have disabled LazyLoading, so it wont return list of staff and roles without the .Include(...). I was tryng to use the roles list on each staff to find the "Owner" but the roles list only have the "Id".

Comment: I would read that as `Select Roles From Staff`, rather than include the roles in the eager loading process?

Comment: Thats what i'm expecting it to do.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what would happen when you project in an include statement and I wonder whether that is how the include function was intended to be used... I would create a small side project and test that.

Comment: I tried change like this "OwnerEmail = d.Staff.Where(x => UserManager.IsInRole(x.Id,"Owner")).FirstOrDefault().Email," But i get exception.

Comment: ....and the exception is?

Answer (score 0):

I query for users and roles simultaneously with ASP.NET Identity very frequently.
My workaround for that is defining a class that has the User and the Role.

Example:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }

    public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the query in your repository to get those values together:

```
public IQueryable<UserRole> GetUsers()
{
    var userQuery = (from usr in context.Users
                     let userRole = usr.Roles.FirstOrDefault()
                     join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                     select new UserRole()
                     {
                         User = usr,
                         Role = role
                     });

    return userQuery;
}
```

Then if you want to get the User emails that have the role "Owner" it would look like this:

```
var emails = GetUsers().Where(ur => ur.Role.Name == "Owner").Select(ur => ur.User.Email);
```

This works for Users with a single role.
In case you work in a multiple roles for every user scenario, then you have to change the `UserRole` class to have an `IQueryable<IdentityRole>` for the roles, and in the query do a join with `usr.Roles` and then grouping the roles by the users, so the query should be like this:

```
public IQueryable<UserRoles> GetUsers()
{
    var userQuery = (from usr in context.Users
                     join userRole in context.Set<IdentityUserRole>() on usr.Id equals userRole.UserId 
                     join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                     group role by usr into roleGroup
                     select new UserRoles()
                     {
                         User = roleGroup.Key,
                         Roles = roleGroup.AsQueryable()
                     });

    return userQuery;
}
```